The selected choice is invalid. Symfony
Tengo un proyecto Symfony en desarrollo con un error en un formulario que me impide avanzar. Parece que el campo que coge del formulario no es el que se espera. El error que me aparece en el navegador es "The selected choice is invalid.Caused by:
Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation {#1475 ▼ Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException {#1007 ▼
#message: "The choice "1" does not exist or is not unique."
formulario:
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
        {

        $builder
            ->add('especialidad', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Especialidad::class,
                'choice_label' => 'nombre',
                'placeholder' => 'Escoge una especialidad',
                'mapped' => true,
                'attr' => ['class' => 'especialidad-selector'],
            ])
            ->add('medico', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Medico::class,
                'choice_label' => function (Medico $medico) {
                    return $medico->getNombre() . ' ' . $medico->getApellidos();
                },
                'placeholder' => 'Primero selecciona una especialidad',
                'choices' => [],
                'mapped' => true,
                'attr' => ['class' => 'medico-selector'],
            ]);
            

            
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'method' => 'post',
            'data_class' => Cita::class,
    
        ]);
    }
}

vista twig:
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Reservar Cita{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Reservar Cita</h1>

    {{ form_start(citaonlineForm) }}
        {{ form_row(citaonlineForm.especialidad) }}
        {{ form_row(citaonlineForm.medico) }}

        <button class="btn btn-primary">Continuar</button>
    {{ form_end(citaonlineForm) }}
    
    <!--incluyo ajax para que no recargue la página al elegir el médico-->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.especialidad-selector').change(function() {
                var especialidadId = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ path('app_cita_medico') }}',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        especialidad_id: especialidadId
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        var $medicoSelect = $('#cita_online_medico');
                        $medicoSelect.html('');
                        if (data.medicos.length > 0) {
                            $medicoSelect.append($('<option>', {
                                value: '',
                                text: 'Escoge un médico'
                            }));
                            $.each(data.medicos, function(key, medico) {
                                $medicoSelect.append($('<option>', {
                                    value: medico.id,
                                    text: medico.nombre
                                }));
                            });
                        } else {
                            $medicoSelect.append($('<option>', {
                                value: '',
                                text: 'No hay médicos disponibles'
                            }));
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script> 
{% endblock %}

Y mi controlador es:
//método select para cita online, elegir especialidad y médico
#[Route('/citaonline', name: 'app_cita_online', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function select(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
    $cita = new Cita(); // Crea una nueva cita
    $form = $this->createForm(CitaOnlineType::class, $cita); // Pasar cita como data para el formulario
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $especialidad = $form->get('especialidad')->getData(); // Obtenemos la especialidad seleccionada del formulario
        $medico = $form->get('medico')->getData(); // Obtenemos el médico seleccionado del formulario

        if (!$especialidad || !$medico) {
            // Manejar el error si la especialidad o el médico no existen
            $this->addFlash('error', 'La especialidad o el médico seleccionado no existe.');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_cita_online');
        }
        
        // Asignar especialidad y médico a la cita
        $cita->setEspecialidad($especialidad);
        $cita->setMedico($medico);
        
        // Guardar la cita en la base de datos
        $entityManager->persist($cita);
        $entityManager->flush();

        // Redireccionar al calendario con los IDs de especialidad y médico
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_cita_calendar', [
            'especialidadId' => $especialidad->getId(),
            'medicoId' => $medico->getId(),
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('cita/citaonline.html.twig', [
        'citaonlineForm' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}


 //manejar la solicitud ajax, devuelve médicos disponibles por especialidad seleccionada
 #[Route('/citamedico', name: 'app_cita_medico', methods: ['POST'])]
 public function medicosPorEspecialidad(Request $request, MedicoRepository $medicoRepository): Response
 {
     $especialidadId = $request->request->get('especialidad_id');
     $medicos = $medicoRepository->findBy(['especialidad' => $especialidadId]);

     $medicosArray = [];
  foreach ($medicos as $medico) {
         $medicosArray[] = [
             'id' => $medico->getId(),
             'nombre' => $medico->getNombre() . ' ' . $medico->getApellidos()
         ];
     }
     
     return $this->json(['medicos' => $medicosArray]);
 }

He probado a incorporar un DataTransformer, pero me da más errores de los que me soluciona.

Dado que tu definición no incluye ninguna opción 'choices' => [], Symfony detecta que un usuario intenta enviar un resultado que no está en los resultados autorizados iniciales. Para evitar esto, puedes, o bien establecer una serie inicial de opciones que contengan todos los valores disponibles o deshabilitar esa validación usando resetViewTransformers(). Revisa esta respuesta para más detalles.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Mil gracias @A.Cedano, lo solucioné finalmente con un POST_SUBMIT.
